# Contar intervalos de un DF dependiendo de otra variable 2

Tags: python

estoy intentando contar una dummy sujeto a la existencia o no de otra dummy. Mi data es así:

```
dummy1  dummy2
 0       0
 0       0
 1       1
 1       0
 1       0
 1       1
 1       0
 1       1
 1       0
 0       0
 0       0 
 1       1
 1       0
 1       1
 1       0
...     ...
```

Necesito que quede así:

```
dummy1  dummy2
 0       0
 0       0
 1       1
 1       0
 1       0
 1       2
 1       0
 1       3
 1       0
 0       0
 0       0 
 1       1
 1       0
 1       2
 1       0
...     ...
```

Es decir, una especie de cumsum en dummy2, mientras que la dummy1 sea 1. Y luego que en el siguiente intervalo de dummy1, se resetee la cuenta. Partiendo desde 1.

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer una especie de groupby cumsum. Por lo que el problema se me ha dividido en 2:
1. Hacer la división por grupos (hice un for, pero tarda mucho) Hay alguna forma más rápida?
2. Luego hacer el cumsum por los grupos hechos.

Comment: Pudieras poner el código del for al que haces referencia?